# How to make a Windows Phone 8.1 TimePicker inherit from the system regional format?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, globalization

When I add a TimePicker control to a Windows Phone 8.1 application, it uses the 12-hour format instead of the regional format configured at the OS level (Settings > Region > Regional Format).

I know I can force the format manually by setting the ClockIdentifier property but I'm looking for a more elegant/global solution that uses the system settings and configures all my controls at once.

If it must be done manually, how to retrieve the system time format?

Answer (score 0):

One option to try is

```
private void SetCaptions()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    this.SuspendLayout();
    for (int i = 0; i != Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        resources.ApplyResources(Controls[i], Controls[i].Name, Program.Culture);
    }
    resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this", Program.Culture);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

(see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25392/Windows-Mobile-Globalization-in-Visual-Studio)

and there is `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`that can be set programmatically.